# How to add entry in Linux man page database

Tags: linux, manpage

I have a manual page for mongoose web server named as mongoose.1 as a result of doing make and make install command to install mongoose web server on my ubuntu 12.04.
But ,the man page entry is not in manual page database.

output on my command line when I did : "man mongoose"

```
akshay@akshay-Inspiron-N5010:~/mongoose$ man mongoose
  No manual entry for mongoose
  See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

I know the path of all man pages where they are stored is:-

```
/usr/local/share/man/
```

I am thankful for your answers in advance.

Comment: Where is the manpage installed? Is the path in `/etc/manpath.config`?

Comment: You should better ask this on superuser.com, stackoverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: @MartinBaulig : Thanks, I will take care for that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The directory where the manpage is installed should be listed either in `/etc/manpath.config` or in the `MANPATH` environment variable. E.g., if the manpage is

```
/opt/mongoose/share/man/man1/mongoose.1
```

then you can set it using

```
MANPATH=/opt/mongoose/share/man man mongoose
```

(or change the `MANPATH` in your `.bashrc` or similar shell startup file).

Comment: My man page path is :
/home/akshay/mongoose/mongoose.1
then what should I do in /etc/manpath.config file under MANPATH mapping table?
also please tell how to access an environment variable to change it's value as you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: You should install the manpage in a directory that has the same structure as `/usr/share/man`, e.g. `/home/akshay/mongoose/man/man1/mongoose.1`, then add `/home/akshay/mongoose/man` to your `MANPATH`. As for changing an environment variable, check your shell's documentation (it's probably Bash).

Comment: To finish up, recreate the database and verify your new pages are available.
    `sudo mandb`

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution:
We have to just copy mongoose.1 which is a man file into folder /usr/share/man/man1/

akshay@akshay-Inspiron-N5010:~/mongoose$ sudo cp mongoose.1 /usr/share/man/man1/

In /usr/share/man/ there are folders named from man1 to man8. I just guessed my man page extension of mongoose.1 is '1' so I copied that into man1 folder.
Am I right on this?

After this step, man mongoose shows the manual page entry successfully.

Comment: You should never install anything in `/usr/share` except through the package manager.

Comment: @AkshayPatil however, you can save it to `/usr/local/share/man/man1/`