# Description to my file using man command

Tags: linux, command-line

I created a small project using C to make some commands in Linux terminal.

I want to add a description to my project to call it when I use `man` command. Such as if my project name is `hello.c`, I want when I write command `man hello.c` to print the description  I wrote for my project. Where do I write this description?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030904/how-to-add-entry-in-linux-man-page-database) but don't know where or how I write the description.

Comment: This answer will help you to solve the problem<br>
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/237910/description-to-my-project-using-man-command/237919?noredirect=1#237919

Answer (score 0):

There are several great tutorials for doing so:

- [How to write a man
  page](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/courses/cs701/Handouts/man_pages.html)
- [Creating your own manpage](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/creatingman.htm)
- [How to write a UNIX man page](http://technicalprose.blogspot.gr/2011/06/how-to-write-unix-man-page.html).

Pick one, and hack away.

If you feel that you are stuck somewhere, take a look at man pages from [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/) utilities like [cat](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/bin/cat/cat.1), [echo](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/bin/echo/echo.1), etc

Comment: Actually,i'm new in Linux world and don't know how to do that i read this links before and can't create my own man page can please help me more ?