# BASH: Creating a man page for your alias

Tags: bash, alias

I have a lot of aliases when working with bash, and sometimes I tend to forget what a certain alias does. Is it possible to create a short description for an alias when running `man <youralias>`?

Comment: Yes, but troff can be tedious to write.

Comment: See this question and answers about creating man page entries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030904/how-to-add-entry-in-linux-man-page-database

Comment: If you type `alias <the alias>`, Bash will remind you what it is. Does that suit?

Answer (score 2):

While there is an answer to this on [How to add entry in Linux man page database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030904/how-to-add-entry-in-linux-man-page-database)

It's easier to do this.

Create a text file with a short paragraph explaining your alias, and then save it to `alias-name.txt`

Get `ronn` (a ruby gem) this will generate a man/troff/roff format file from your text.

```
gem install ronn
```

Then convert your text file:

```
ronn -r alias-name.txt
```

A file `./alias-name` will be created, move it to your local shared man path.  eg.

```
mv alias-name /usr/local/share/man1/alias-name.1
```

Now admire your handiwork...

```
man alias-name
```

To get more advanced in your formatting look at the ronn-format (based on Markdown.) https://rtomayko.github.io/ronn/ronn-format.7.html