# Man page: How to include a file in your manual page

Tags: linux, manpage

I am writing a man page for my software and I written few documents which I need it to be a part of man page.

Is it possible to include the contents of those documents in my man page?

Comment: http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/creatingman.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add entry in Linux man page database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030904/how-to-add-entry-in-linux-man-page-database)

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-creating-a-manpage/

Comment: The links above do not show how to include other files.