# `man` can't access custom manpages

Tags: zsh, manpage

I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14030997/3156085) to add some manpages on my computer, but I still can't open it with `man`.

I set `$MANPATH` to `/usr/local/man` (`export MANPATH=/usr/local/man` in my `~/.zshrc`, and sourced it) and copied my manpage files to `/usr/local/man/man3`. Yet `man` doesn't find the pages I want to access :

```
$ echo $MANPATH
/usr/local/man
$ tree /usr/local/man
/usr/local/man
└── man3
    ├── mlx.1
    ├── mlx_loop.1
    ├── mlx_new_image.1
    ├── mlx_new_window.1
    └── mlx_pixel_put.1

1 directory, 5 files
$ man mlx
No manual entry for mlx
$ man 3 mlx
No manual entry for mlx in section 3
```

Why do I get this error and what could I do?

Comment: Did you `export MANPATH`?

Comment: @MicahElliott Yes, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the files are either in the wrong directory or have an incorrect extension. 
The directory name indicates that it contains manpages for section 3 (Library calls) but the filename extensions suggest that the manpages belong to section 1 (Executable programs or shell commands).

You should be able to check which is the case - for example for `mlx.1` - with the following command

```
man /usr/local/man/man3/mlx.1
```

This should show the name of the manpage (probably in uppercase) followed by the section number in parentheses at the very beginning.

If it shows `MLX(1)` move the file `mlx.1` into the directory `/usr/local/man/man1` (or just rename `man3` if all files belong to section 1). If it shows `MLX(3)`, just rename the file to `mlx.3`.